# How to prove the function $y = \sin x$ is not a closed function?

Tags: general-topology, functions, closed-map

I came across a question:

> Suppose that $f(x) = \sin x$ is a function from $\mathbb R$ to $[-1,1]$. How do I prove the function $f(x) = \sin x$ is not a closed function?

By "closed function", I mean a function such that the image of any closed set is closed.

Comment: What is your definition of "closed function"? The first one I found by googling _is_ satisfied by the sine.

Comment: Closed function is a function such that image of every closed set is closed.

Comment: If the closed set is bounded, then the image is, of course compact, so to get a counterexample, you must look at unbounded closed sets.

Comment: @copper.hat yes: every compact subset of real line iff it is closed and bounded.

Comment: @Ben Millwood: Thanks for your revising the question:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Closed function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_function) is a function such that image of every closed set is closed.

It is relatively easy to see that, for any $\varepsilon>0$, every $\varepsilon$-discrete subset of real line is closed. (A subset $A$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ is called *$\varepsilon$-discrete* if for any two distinct points $x,y\in A$ we have $d(x,y)\ge\varepsilon$. For subsets of real line, this condition means $|x-y|\ge\varepsilon$.)

Can you find a sequence $(x_n)$ with the following properties?

- $x_n\in(2n\pi,(2n+1)\pi)$ (which implies that $\{x_n; n\in\mathbb N\}$ is an $\varepsilon$-discrete subset for any $\varepsilon<\pi$)
- $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sin x_n =y$ but $y\notin\{\sin x_n; n\in\mathbb N\}$

If $(x_n)$ fulfills the above properties, then $A=\{x_n; n\in\mathbb N\}$ is a closed set, but the image of this set is not closed.

Comment: Is $x_n= 2n\pi + 0.5\pi - \frac{1}{n} \pi$ OK?

Comment: O, thanks. This is I want to express.

Comment: Seems o.k. to me. (It will be a discrete subset and $\sin x_n$ converges to $\sin\frac\pi2=1$.) Did you understood how this solves your question?

Comment: I understand a little. By your method, does it mean that we find that a closed set $A$ such that its image $f(A)$ is not closed, for its cluster is not in itself?

Comment: Yes, what you wrote is correct.